# Ruby: Get/print file pointer current poistion

Tags: ruby

I am working on log files. Basically there are set of files in a directory with log messages. So at the beginning of the application I have to look into directory and update each files,current file pointer position into DB.
I have looked into *IO::SEEK_CUR*, somehow its not helpful for me.
Is there any alternate where I can get file pointer current position of a file?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-lineno

Comment: please define "file pointer current position"

Comment: [IO#pos or IO#tell](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-tell)

Comment: Hello Stefan, Log files keep growing frequently. So considering that file pointer position keeps on changing. Getting EOF position is also fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Cremno! That's exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you Arup.

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/File.html

Answer (score 2):

`file.pos` - returns current position of cursor, while you read/write to file